why is it returning negative numbers (encrypted pin)?
hi this is my first time using this website.
i dont know why its returning negative numbers when i run the program. i have the 8.2 netbeans ver idk if that has anything to do with this
this is how it should be.
Sample run1 :
Enter your key: 2
Enter your 5-Digit Pin Code: 12345
The Encrypted Pin is: 76543
Enter your 5-Digit Pin Code: 11220
The Encrypted Pin is: 24433
Enter your 5-Digit Pin Code: 10000
The Encrypted Pin is: 22223
Enter your 5-Digit Pin Code: 9
Thank you !

sample run 2:
Enter your key: 6
Your key should be an integer from 1 to 4

this is my code
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication13 {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        


        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter your key:");
        int key = scan.nextInt();
        
        int pincode, digit, encrypteddigit,encryptedpin=0;
        
        if (key >= 1 && key <= 4) {

            do {
                System.out.print("Enter your 5-Digit pin code: ");
                pincode = scan.nextInt();

                
                if (pincode >= 10000 && pincode <= 99999) {
                    
                    while (pincode> 0) {
                        
                        
                        
                        digit = pincode % 10;
                       
                        encrypteddigit = (digit + key)%10;
                        encryptedpin= encryptedpin*10+encrypteddigit;
                        
                        pincode /= 10;}
                        System.out.println("The encrypted pin is: "+ encryptedpin );
                       
                    
                } else {
                    System.out.println("thank you!");
                    break;
                }

            } while (true);

        } else {
            System.out.println("Your key should be an integer between 1 to 4");
        }

        
    }
}

this was the result when i run the program
run:
Enter your key:2
Enter your 5-Digit pin code: 12345
The encrypted pin is: 76543
Enter your 5-Digit pin code: 22007
The encrypted pin is: -935542348   **(why is it giving this?)**
Enter your 5-Digit pin code: 9
thank you!
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 24 seconds)


Think carefully about the logic of the code when you try using it more than once. After "encrypting" the first pin, what will the value of encryptedpin look like? Therefore, when you start the loop for the second pin, what will it look like? Will it be equal to zero? Should it be? Can you think of a way to fix that? (Hint: what part of your code makes it equal to zero, ever? When does that happen? When should it happen?)

Before we get into the details of this, you're using the word "encrypted". An encrypted token is able to be decrypted. If and when your algo works, how do you propose to decrypt the result?

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Before asking more questions, please read [ask] and take the [tour]. I have given you hints to find the simple logical problem in your code, but it's important to understand that Stack Overflow is not for questions like this, which is why I won't use the answer section and give a clear answer. It is your responsibility before posting to locate what is wrong in the code; we don't fix code here, but instead answer questions that can be useful to other people, by serving as general reference.

@g00se decryption here is trivial given the key value, as this is essentially just a simple Vigenere cipher using digit symbols rather than letters. But that is beside the point: the most important thing here is that the question is not suitable for Stack Overflow, as the problem is caused by a typo.

@KarlKnechtel oh sorry im new to this. thanks for the feedback, i will keep it in mind!

You are not resetting the encryptedpin variable for the next 5 digit pin code iteration. When you adjust your code as follow:
System.out.println("encrypted pin before: "+encryptedpin);
encryptedpin= encryptedpin*10+encrypteddigit;
System.out.println("encrypted pin after: "+encryptedpin);

and run your first iteration with the input 12345 you will get the following output:
Enter your key:2
Enter your 5-Digit pin code: 12345
encrypted pin before: 0
encrypted pin after: 7
encrypted pin before: 7
encrypted pin after: 76
encrypted pin before: 76
encrypted pin after: 765
encrypted pin before: 765
encrypted pin after: 7654
encrypted pin before: 7654
encrypted pin after: 76543
The encrypted pin is: 76543
Enter your 5-Digit pin code:

But when you enter the next 5 digit pin code, you will work on the previous last encrypted pin value. You will notice this with the additional output you get:
Enter your key:2
Enter your 5-Digit pin code: 12345
encrypted pin before: 0
encrypted pin after: 7
encrypted pin before: 7
encrypted pin after: 76
encrypted pin before: 76
encrypted pin after: 765
encrypted pin before: 765
encrypted pin after: 7654
encrypted pin before: 7654
encrypted pin after: 76543
The encrypted pin is: 76543
Enter your 5-Digit pin code: 11220
encrypted pin before: 76543          <-- no reset here
encrypted pin after: 765432
encrypted pin before: 765432
encrypted pin after: 7654324
encrypted pin before: 7654324
encrypted pin after: 76543244
encrypted pin before: 76543244
encrypted pin after: 765432443
encrypted pin before: 765432443
encrypted pin after: -935610159      <-- integer overflow
The encrypted pin is: -935610159
Enter your 5-Digit pin code:

Eventually, you will run into an integer overflow, see What is an integer overflow error?
The solution is to call encryptedpin=0 before the next 5 digit pin code iteration, so it restarts at 0.

thank you so much for the clear answer. i even asked chat gpt but it kept confusing me.
